# Error: Can't load file from uriString when upload audio file Android

Tags: android, react-native, file-upload, attachment, quickblox

I am getting error message `Error: Can't load file from uriString` when uploading audio and PDF files with Quickblox in React Native Android app. It is working for images and videos. Quickblox documentation confirms it supports all file formats for chat attachment. Could someone please guide me how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer from QuickBlox support team, they recommended to check the archive with a sample code in order to send any files as chat message attachments. Per my check works fine with .pdf, .mp3

This sample is not officially released so I can provide you only with a Google drive link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C2Rfop3qbLl693UmHA03O3Fdbdy6dVcq/view?usp=sharing